# Earn Area 51 referral awards

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, badges, area-51

The point of Area51 is to get critical mass for an idea for a SE site and this is done by building a community.  I would argue that we should reward those who show that they can successfully build a community.  If someone refers someone else to a SE proposal and that person then ends up following it, then the referrer should be given a rep award on Area51, or maybe a (bronze) badge.  Not exactly sure what the award should be right now as I'm just getting acquainted with things there and don't have a good gauge on balance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was completed in the [**Mafia Wars: The Area 51 Commitment Phase**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53075/mafia-wars-the-area-51-commitment-phase) question.

Answer (score 0):

The sentiment is admirable but the semantics and implementation would probably be pretty hairy. For now, I would suggest that the "reward" for getting experts to follow your site is that you get a fantastic proposal.